# Utilizar date a string y arraylist

Tags: java, date, arraylist

llevo poco con Java y me surge el problema de por qué no me sale en consola los objetos creados en el "main". Todavia tengo conceptos algo dudosos. El ejercicio se trata de crear "Cliente" y luego la fecha ed nacimiento pasarla a String ¿Podrías decirme cual es el error de cuando se ejecuta no aparezca en la consola?

Muchas gracias de antemano

cliente.java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Cliente {

// Atributos de Cliente
private String nombre;
private Date fechaNacimiento;


// Constructor con parametros
public Cliente (String nombre, String fechaNacimiento) throws ParseException {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fechaNacimiento = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(fechaNacimiento);
        }

// Getters
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public String getFechaNacimiento() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").format(fechaNacimiento);
    }

@Override
public String toString(){
    return nombre + ", " + fechaNacimiento;

}
}
```

OrdenaCliente.java (Este me lo dan hecho)

```
public class OrdenaClientes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Cliente c1 = new Cliente("Pepe","08/08/1976");
            Cliente c2 = new Cliente("Ines","11/02/1938");
            Cliente c3 = new Cliente("Pepa","04/03/1988");
            Cliente c4 = new Cliente("Charo","01/08/1977");
            Cliente c5 = new Cliente("Paqui","04/12/1986");
            Cliente c6 = new Cliente("Alberto","08/08/1977");
            Cliente c7 = new Cliente("Alberto","03/04/1992");
            
            ArrayList<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
            listaClientes.add(c1);
            listaClientes.add(c2);
            listaClientes.add(c3);
            listaClientes.add(c4);
            listaClientes.add(c5);
            listaClientes.add(c6);
            listaClientes.add(c7);

            System.out.println("Lista:");
            System.out.println();
            muestraLista(listaCliente);
``
```

Comment: Buenas, Lorenzo, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Puedes copiar el código del método muestraLista?

Comment: Esa parte me la pasan así. El ejercicio es más largo pero esa parte es así. La parte del método muestraLista no está.  Con el toString() creia que ya debia salir cuando se ejecuta

Comment: Pero no estás invocando ese método toString en ningún sitio. Creo que la idea es que implementes tú el método muestraLista que lo único que tiene que hacer es recorrer la lista de clientes escribiendo uno a uno los clientes contenidos en ella.

Comment: En esa parte entonces es donde estoy perdido. :(

Comment: Aquí tienes un pequeño tutorial en español sobre el uso de listas en java. Incluye el código para imprimir por pantalla todos los elementos de una lista http://panamahitek.com/el-uso-de-listas-en-java/

Comment: y qué es lo que te sale por consola?

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes es que primero está mal el nombre de la lista que pasas como parámetro en el método `muestraLista(listaCliente);` realmente es `muestraLista(listaClientes);` y supongo que tu método ***muestraLista()*** debe tener un cuerpo así:

```
private static void muestraLista(ArrayList<Cliente> lista) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(lista.get(i)+"\n");
    }
}
```

entonces el resultado seria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Correcto, el error de "listaClientes" es mio. Pero me piden que en Cliente.java, el método toString, también realizar el cambio de formato, para que la cadena de texto que se genera, tenga el formato solicitado (dd/MM/yyy). Ahí me he quedado bloqueado sin saber ya que no sé como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo tu único error es que no usas `getFechaNacimiento()` para el
`toString()`. Si no lo usas, java invocará al `toString()` del objeto `fechaNacimiento`, y supongo que eso te devolverá un formato no adecuado. Recuerda que la lógica que tienes para que la fecha de nacimiento de salida esté formateada está en el getter.

En definitiva, lo único que tienes que hacer es cambiar el `toString()`:

```java
@Override
public String toString(){
    return nombre + ", " + getFechaNacimiento();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es que quieres mostrar el toString sin formatear la salida, tu método quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
@Override
    public String toString(){
        return nombre + ", " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").format(fechaNacimiento);

    }
```

También puedes hacer uso de los métodos get llamando desde la clase `OrdenaClientes`

La forma de mostrar tus datos desde otra clase es la siguiente:

```
public class OrdenaClientes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        try {
            Cliente c1 = new Cliente("Pepe","08/08/1976");
            Cliente c2 = new Cliente("Ines","11/02/1938");
            Cliente c3 = new Cliente("Pepa","04/03/1988");
            Cliente c4 = new Cliente("Charo","01/08/1977");
            Cliente c5 = new Cliente("Paqui","04/12/1986");
            Cliente c6 = new Cliente("Alberto","08/08/1977");
            Cliente c7 = new Cliente("Alberto","03/04/1992");

            ArrayList<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
            listaClientes.add(c1);
            listaClientes.add(c2);
            listaClientes.add(c3);
            listaClientes.add(c4);
            listaClientes.add(c5);
            listaClientes.add(c6);
            listaClientes.add(c7);

            System.out.println("Lista:");
            System.out.println();
            muestraLista(listaClientes); 
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error encontrado: "+ex);
        }
    }
    
    private static void muestraLista(ArrayList<Cliente> lista) {
        System.out.println("Usando los metodos get");
        for(Cliente c:lista){
            System.out.println(c.getNombre()+" , "+c.getFechaNacimiento());
        }
        
        System.out.println("Usando toString \n");
        for(Cliente c:lista){
            System.out.println(c.toString());
        }
    }
}
```